# Placing a rock piece at a 45 degree angle

Tags: design, angles

I'd like to place [this rock](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11127&C=15#T=C&C=15) at a 45 degree angle to the ground. What's the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and least obstructive way would be to use a [65578 Bar, Angled with Stud on End](https://rebrickable.com/parts/65578/bar-angled-with-stud-on-end/) in conjunction with [an Apollo stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=85861&utm_source=rebrickable#T=A).

Comment: Apollo stud? I've never heard of that piece being called the Apollo stud. Why is it called that?

Comment: @technicguy1 it's far from being official, but some people call it thus due to a misheard phrase by the author of a popular Lego blog: http://www.newelementary.com/p/glossary.html?m=1